# Apply CSS onclick

Tags: javascript, css

How do I apply these css to the body with my current javascript code

```
-webkit-filter: blur(20px);
-moz-filter: blur(15px);
-o-filter: blur(15px);
-ms-filter: blur(15px);
filter: blur(15px);
opacity: 0.95;
```

Here is my javascript

```
<script>
    $("a:nth-child(4)").click(function () {
        $(".artists").animate({width:'toggle'},500);                 
});
</script>
```

Comment: `body` as in `<body>` tag? and when? onclick of `a:nth-child(4)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a class for this and then apply it on click

**CSS**

```
.urClass{
  -webkit-filter: blur(20px);
  -moz-filter: blur(15px);
  -o-filter: blur(15px);
  -ms-filter: blur(15px);
  filter: blur(15px);
  opacity: 0.95;
}
```

**JS**

```
$("a:nth-child(4)").click(function () {
    $(".artists").animate({width:'toggle'},500);
    $('body').addClass('urClass');                 
});
```

Comment: and how do you remove the class on reclick?

Comment: @MichaelStClair use a toggle.

Comment: @MichaelStClair by **$('body').toggleClass('urClass');**

Comment: the way to close it, and the original button are not blurred

Answer (score 1):

better to just use [.addClass](http://docs.jquery.com/Addclass) even if you have 1 or more. It's more maintainable and readable.

If you really have the urge to do multiple css props then use

```
$("a:nth-child(4)").click(function () {
    $(".artists").animate({width:'toggle'},500);
    $('body').css({
                 '-webkit-filter': 'blur(20px)', 
                 '-moz-filter': 'blur(15px)', 
                 '-o-filter: blur(15px)', 
                 '-ms-filter': 'blur(15px)', 
                 'filter': 'blur(15px)', 
                 'opacity': '0.95'
                 });               
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without jQuery:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
            var anchor = anchors[i];
            anchor.onclick = function() {
                alert('ho ho ho');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And to do it without jQuery, and only on a specific class (ex: hohoho):

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
            var anchor = anchors[i];
            if(/\bhohoho\b/).match(anchor.className)) {
                anchor.onclick = function() {
                    alert('ho ho ho');
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
If you are okay with using jQuery, then you can do this for all anchors:

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a').click(function() {
            alert('ho ho ho');
        });
    });
</script>
```

And this jQuery snippet to only apply it to anchors with a specific class:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.hohoho').click(function() {
            alert('ho ho ho');
        });
    });
</script>
```